# TicTacToe - trouble alternating players

Tags: javascript, tic-tac-toe

First mouse click gives me the expected 'x' marker but the next mouse click results in the alert ("Player o: tile has already been selected) even though the grid-item is blank. What am I doing wrong?

In the HTML body, I have created a 3x3 grid, 9 gridItems in total.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

        let grid = $("#grid-container") 
        let gridItem = $(".grid-item")

        function select(){ 
            for (i = 0; i < gridItem.length; i++){
                gridItem[i].addEventListener("click", function(){ 
                    if ($(this).html() == ""){
                        $(this).html("x");
                        nextSelect(); 
                    } else {alert ("Player X: tile has already been selected"); select()}
                })
            }
        }

        function nextSelect(){
            for (i = 0; i < gridItem.length; i++){
                gridItem[i].addEventListener("click", function(){  
                    if ($(this).html() == ""){
                        $(this).html("o");
                        select();
                    } else {alert ("Player o: tile has already been selected"); nextSelect()}   
                })
            }   
        }

        select()

    });
```

Comment: The `addEventListener` should be executed only once. Your problem is that you're adding multiple event handlers.

Comment: For both functions, if I take away the if() statements that check for blanks, the alternating of x and o works fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The addEventListener should be executed only once. Your problem is that you're adding multiple event handlers. A possible version in the snippet bellow.

The idea is that you only need one function and attach it to click event only once per cell, which is done with jQuery `.click(callback)`. To manage the turns you can use a boolean variable (`isTurnOfPlayerOne`).

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  let isTurnOfPlayerOne = true;
  $(".grid-item").click(handleClick);

  function handleClick() {
    if ($(this).html() == "&nbsp;") {
      let symbol = (isTurnOfPlayerOne ? "x" : "o");
      $(this).html(symbol);
    } else {
      alert("Tile has already been selected");
    }

    isTurnOfPlayerOne = !isTurnOfPlayerOne;
  }

});
```

```css
.grid-item {
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  display: inline-block;
  border: solid 1px #000;
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 3px;
  line-height: 30px;
  font-size: 30px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="grid-container">
  <div class="grid-item">&nbsp;</div>
  <div class="grid-item">&nbsp;</div>
  <div class="grid-item">&nbsp;</div>
  <br/>
  <div class="grid-item">&nbsp;</div>
  <div class="grid-item">&nbsp;</div>
  <div class="grid-item">&nbsp;</div>
  <br/>
  <div class="grid-item">&nbsp;</div>
  <div class="grid-item">&nbsp;</div>
  <div class="grid-item">&nbsp;</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Aren't semicolons missing at the end of two lines?

Comment: You are right, I saw missing semicolons in these lines: `let symbol = (isTurnOfPlayerOne ? "x" : "o")` and `isTurnOfPlayerOne = !isTurnOfPlayerOne`. I have added them. If you talk about the closing bracket `}`, it doesn't go there. Anyway, javascript also works without the missing ones, it's very tolerant :P (as you could check if you did run the code snippet with the previous verson)